# Sales of same date last year

Tags: r

I have a `DF <-(ID,Year,Sales)` and I want to create a fourth column `LastYearSale` which selects Sales of last year. For example if have:

```
ID Year Sales

1 01/01/2015 50000 
2 01/01/2014 20000
```

I want output like this:

```
ID    Year  Sales  LastYearSales

1 01/01/2015 50000  20000
2 01/01/2014 20000
```

Comment: Try `library(dplyr);DF %>% mutate(LastYearSales= lead(Sales))`

Answer (score 0):

If your `Year` column is not in `Date` class then convert it it into `Date` class first by

```
df$Year <- as.Date(df$Year, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

You can then try with `lubridate` package

```
library(lubridate)
df$LastYearSales <-  c(df[df$Year %in% (as.Date(ymd(df$Year) - years(1))), ]$Sales,  NA)
df
# ID       Year   Sales    LastYearSales
# 1  1 2015-01-01 50000        20000
# 2  2 2014-01-01 20000           NA
```